# OAuth with multiple youtube accounts

Tags: oauth, youtube

I am writing a Windows desktop application that uploads video to youtube.  I am using the code below.

```
           UserCredential credential;
        /*
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {

            // dependent on the client_secrets.json file           
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
      }*/

      ClientSecrets clientSecret = new ClientSecrets();
      clientSecret.ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
      clientSecret.ClientSecret = "yyyyyy";
      credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          clientSecret,
          new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
          "user",
          CancellationToken.None);
```

What I have not been able to determine is how to switch between different youtube accounts.  I have more than one youtube account and would like to use them for different scenarios within the desktop application.

When I originally used the commented out snippet of code, it used the json file for the user credentials - but that is static information.  I then changed the code to what you see above - but intend to change the code to use different values for  ClientSecret to select the corresponding youtube account.

The first time I ran the application, it prompts me to select which google/youtube account to use - and works correctly - but I do not know how to switch to different accounts in code.  I have read through the google api on this, but cannot determine how to do this.  I have tried not providing a ClientSecret, but then get an exception that no ClientSecret was provided, which makes sense.

Comment: Does this Help? https://www.accountchooser.com/learnmore.html

Comment: @jwilleke - no, that is for web projects.